# Regex.Split on specific characters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to make my string split on any `Non Word Characters (\W)` including `spaces` but **not** including these characters : `.`, `_`, `$`. also I'm trying to **keep** any delimiters of `Regex.Split` **except** for `spaces`

how i can do that? i've read on many questions but it doesn't make sense. here is my latest code :

```
string[] result = Regex.Split (source, @"(\W[^(.|_|#|$)])");
```

EDIT :

an example here

```
      using System.Text;
```

i want :

`using` _ `System.Text` _ `;`

(current) result is :

_  _ `using` _ `System.Text` _ `;` _

Comment: you need to escape them with `\\`.

Comment: Please include a sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!\.|#|_|\$|\s)(\W)|\s+
```

Try this.A `lookahead` will make sure it is not split by those characters.

Comment: works, but `blank spaces` still included and `delimiters` aren't included in result

Comment: thanks, delimiters now included in result, but `blank spaces` still included also. is there any way to excude this from my result?

Comment: @WillandM try `(?!\.|#|_|\$)\s*((?!\s)\W)\s*|\s+`

Comment: OK, maybe I can get workaround for this, since it's a blank space, i can exclude that externally. thanks also for knowing me about that tool

Comment: @vks: A negative look-ahead is not efficient here since there is class subtraction in .NET. For JavaScript, it would be the only way, but it is not .NET style. Just tested on [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/), yours is 24% slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following .NET-specific `[\W-[._$#\s]])|\s+` regex and leverage the C# LINQ to remove empty array items:

```
var txt = "      using System.Text;";
var splts = Regex.Split(txt, @"([\W-[._$#\s]])|\s+").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
```

Output:

[image]

The regex - `[\W-[._$#\s]])|\s+` - uses a [character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) that is way more efficient than look-arounds as it leverages all optimizations of .NET regex engine. `[\W-[._$#\s]]` means *any non-word character excluding `.`, `_`, `$`, `#`, `whitespace`*.

Comment: @WillandM: There is no way to get rid of those NULL matches, that is why it is a real-life solution to remove empty array/list/collection members from the `Split` results.